# How to bind Editor Control in scrollview xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am creating chat user interface. I have taken custom editor control at bottom in by view above Flowlistview. When my editor get focus and keyboard present at that time it shifts up entire view with header section in iOS. In android it's working fine because of UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust property. But how to manage this in iOS?

//Add the following code: to fix ScrollView behaviour when keyboard is shown

```
Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
```

I have tried to add Editor inside scroll view but that is also not working, when I'm trying to type in editor it goes down and keyboard remains open in this case.

> In short how to handle keyboard shifting my views up in iOS
> xamarin.forms?

I have attached screen shot here, any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Hi, this phenomenon in iOS results from the root view of this page move it's content offset up . If you can only change the content offset of scrollview , this problem will be fixed in iOS .

Comment: How I can achieve this? can you share your solution? @JuniorJiang-MSFT

Comment: That needs custom renderer . If using `DLToolkit.Forms.Controls.`FlowListView`  , not sure can achieve that .

Comment: Yes, I have used Flowlist View to show message threads, then what should I do.  @JuniorJiang-MSFT

Answer (score 0):

you could install this nugget [Xamarin.IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/TheEightBot/Xamarin.IQKeyboardManager)

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        IQKeyboardManager.SharedManager.Enable = true;
        LoadApplication(new App());
        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
}
```

[Reference](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/156221/keyboard-covering-textfields-when-popping-up-xamarin-ios)

Comment: It's in there but still I'm facing this issue

Comment: "I have tried to add Editor inside scroll view but that is also not working, when I'm trying to type in editor it goes down and keyboard remains open in this case." 
Try add all your layout inside the ScrollView.

Comment: I can not do that as I have messages in list view @Ramon Farizel

Comment: I found this link https://www.flokri.com/development/xamarin-development/howto-xamarin-forms-automatically-move-controls-when-keyboard-is-shown. Maybe could be useful

Comment: I have got this solution already https://xamgirl.com/adjusting-elements-when-keyboard-shows-in-xamarin-forms/ but it's not solving my issue.